# Index-free notation indulgence!

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation, vector-fields

I have been try to find as an exercise for myself the most suitable coordinate-free form of the following equation found in Misner, Thorne, Wheeler's [*Gravitation*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691177793/gravitation) (p. 84)

\begin{equation}
v^\ell = (F_{ij}F^{ij})_{,k}~g^{k\ell}
\end{equation}

where $F = F_{ij}~ g^i\otimes g^j$ is a 2-form, and $g^{k\ell}$ is the metric. I know, and as the it is hinted upon, that $v^\ell$ are components of the vector $\boldsymbol{v}$ in the basis $\lbrace g_\ell\rbrace$, so I can have

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{v} = g^\sharp ~\nabla f
\end{equation}

where $g^\sharp$ is the musical isomorphism that turns the 1-form $\nabla f$ into a vector. My problem is how to exactly/rigorously denote the scalar $f = F_{ij}F^{ij}$. This is what I have got so far:

If I were to define $F^\textsf{T} = F_{ij} ~g^j\otimes g^i$, then by the properties of dyads I can have a 2-form via

\begin{align}
F F^\textsf{T} &= F_{ij}F_{k\ell} ~(g^i\otimes g^j)(g^\ell\otimes g^k)\\
&= F_{ij}F_{k\ell} ~g^{j\ell} ~(g^i\otimes g^k)
\end{align}

where I have employed $g^j \cdot g^\ell = g^j(g^\ell) = g^{j\ell}$.
Now, if I take the trace with respect to the metric, I will have
\begin{align}
f = \text{tr}_g (FF^\textsf{T}) = F_{ij}F_{k\ell} ~g^{j\ell} ~g^i (g^k) = F_{ij}F_{k\ell} ~g^{j\ell} g^{ik} = F_{ij}F^{ij}.
\end{align}

That is to say, I have
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{v} = g^\sharp ~\nabla ~\text{tr}_g (FF^\textsf{T}).
\end{equation}

However, there are some confusions for me. If all my actions have been correct, how would I get  $FF^\textsf{T}$ from the 4-form $F\otimes F$, since in the book the authors suggest to contract the tensor product $F\otimes F$ on its 1st and 3rd slots, as well as on the 2nd and 3rd slots. Since I did not know how to denote such actions in a coordinate-free notation, I resorted to the transpose idea (which I borrowed from quantum mechanics). Is it a  partial trace with respect to the second slots of each $F$? Are there more rigorous ways of telling the story?

**Motivation:** I am not trying to study GR. My goal is to study nonlinear elasticity and continuum mechanics, whose textbooks use index-free notation. Sometimes it is very hard to make sense of the equations. I came across this exercise and I found it very helpful to my understanding of the matter.

Comment: You'll enjoy this book https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511807497 .In that framework your eqn should be something like $v=\nabla(F \cdot F)$

Comment: Interesting book! However, upon a quick check, he also defines $\nabla$ as a covector, hence your equality is somewhat suspicious.  My $tr(FF^t)$ is an inner product, I think, as you also mentioned, however $F$ being a 2-form makes me hesitant. I was more eager to know whether that transposition is justified, or if I can act $F$ on $F^t$ in the manner I wrote. If so, I think $v=g\nabla |F^2|$ is a good way to go.

Comment: IIRC there are no covectors in that book - the upper index e's refer to a "reciprocal basis". Upper and lower index things are both vectors. This is possible because an inner product is present, creating the canonical isomorphism, and it helps make many expressions easier to physically interpret

Comment: Here's the thing: field tensors F (and two-forms more generally) are "really" bivectors, not tensors. So the "right" coordinate-free framework is either Clifford algebra (if a metric is present), or differential forms (if not). Both can be embedded in tensor algebra, but that doesn't mean they should be. (I know saying F isn't "really" a tensor may sound like craziness... but if you give that book another two hours you'll see ;) )

Comment: Or [Hestenes and Sobzyk](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-009-6292-7) if you're more inclined for the formal

Comment: @JoeSchindler Your last two comments were very helpful!! Also Doran's book is marvelous! Thanks!

Comment: Great..... enjoy!